# Finding the degree of a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Find the degree $[K:F]$ of the following field extensions:
>   (a) $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$
>   (b) $K=\mathbb{C}(\sqrt{7})$, $F=\mathbb{C}$
>   (c) $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{35})$, $F=\mathbb{Q}$
>   (d) $K=\mathbb{R}(s)$, $F=\mathbb{R}$, where $s^3-4s^2+6s+6=0$

Firstly, I should mention that I am very new to field theory; this is for an algebraic number theory book that I'm trying to follow, but the only algebra I know is group theory.

I know the degree is the dimension of $K$ as an $F$-vector space, so I need to find a basis for each of the above $K$'s. I'm pretty sure (a) has degree 2, as does (c), because $\sqrt{35}=\sqrt{7}\sqrt{5}$, so we might as well simply look at $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{35})$.

I'm not sure what to do about (d), and (b) puzzles me because the complex numbers already contain $\sqrt{7}$. Does this mean it has degree 1?

I'm sorry my question can't be more specific.

Comment: Are you sure you can look *simply* at $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt{35}):=\{a+b\sqrt{35}\;:\;a,b\in\Bbb Q\}\;$ ? For this you'd have to be able to show, for example, that $\;\sqrt5\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{35})\implies \sqrt5=a+b\sqrt{35}\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb Q\;$ Are you sure you can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about (a), its degree is 2.

For (b), your suspicion is also correct, its degree is 1 since $\sqrt{7}$ already belongs to $\mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed so it has no finite extensions).

Your reasoning for (c) isn't quite right. Yes, $\sqrt{5} \cdot \sqrt{7} = \sqrt{35}$ but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{35})$ is strictly smaller than $K$. Consider instead $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. $L$ is of degree 2 over $F=\mathbb{Q}$. However, $\sqrt{7}$ doesn't belong to $L$. $K=L(\sqrt{7})$ has degree 2 over $L$. Thus $[K:F] = [K:L]\cdot [L:F] = 2 \cdot 2 =4$.

As for (d), I'm confused as well. Maybe your question is missing something, but if $s^3-4s^2+6s+6=0$, then $s$ can be either real of one of two (conjugate) complex roots. If $s$ is real then $K=\mathbb{R}$ and the extension has degree 1. If $s$ is complex, then $K=\mathbb{C}$ and the extension has degree 2.

Comment: There is perhaps a typo - $s$ can either be the real root **or** it can be one of the two conjugate complex roots.

Comment: I've typed the question exactly as it appears. I suppose I'll just mention this fact in my solution and leave it at that.